# meaning of a sentence in this paraghraph

Tags: meaning

> A manager's core challenge is to blend the diversity (and imperfections) of their team into a group which wants to work together each day and produce results on behalf of the organisation. Yet for many managers the very concept of social within the enterprise still remains a vexed issue with scant recognition of how it could help. The fact is that an ESN, properly designed and implemented, provides the grease which lubricates the alignment of employees with an organisation's core values and beliefs. **This provides a purpose to come to work and a reason to produce results on behalf of the organisation.** An ESN also provides the same lubricant to the alignment of employees with the organisation's key objectives and strategy - this helps make a team's output effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your sentence

> This provides a purpose to come to work and a reason to produce results on behalf of the organisation.

refers to the motivation people will have to go to work if Enterprise Social Networking (ESN) is correctly implemented.  The assumption is that if the employees are better informed by the company and have stronger ties to with their coworkers, communication, team work, and production will become more effective.